# Using RegEx in n++'s find and replace feature, how do I replace multiple unwanted words from multiple lines?

Tags: regex

Let me elaborate. I have lines:

bear
not available
page not found
lion
error
tiger
rhino

I want to get rid of the lines that say "not available, page not found, or error" by replacing them with nothing or empty spaces so it reads:

bear
lion

tiger
rhino

Is there a way to execute this job with one line of RegEx code in n++'s find & replace feature? Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What is n++?  Do you mean Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this was much simpler than I anticipated.

The RegEx line of [not available|page not found|error] works. Thanks for reading and I apologize for my noobism.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about n++, but you can generally do this in regex's with a "global" flag: e.g. in javaScript:

```
lines = lines.replace(/not available|page not found|error/g,"");
```